# Python - measure function execution time with decorator

Tags: python, time, decorator, pow

I have the next problem:
For example, I have a function (this is just an example to make things simple) called my_pow, that takes two arguments and return a^b, and it looks like this:

```
def my_pow(a, b):
    res = a ** b
    return res
    # or just return a ** b, it doesn't really matter
```

And I have a decorator that should measure for how long did the decorated function ran.

```
def decorator_timer(some_function):
    from time import time

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time()
        result = some_function(*args, **kwargs)
        return result, time()-t1
    return wrapper
```

And the problem is, I can't really measure the time for how long did it took a function to calculate for example 99999 ** 99999. I can either calculate it and print res, this way I'll get a correct execution time but None will be returned from a my_pow() function, or I can return res, but the time it took to run will be something 0.0001, though obviously decorated function is running for much longer, actually around 3 seconds. Is there a way to measure how long did it take to run that function, and at the same time return a res value from a function?

Comment: you can return several variables with `return a, b, c` and get them with `x, y, z = run function()`

Comment: @Emil105 You mean measure execution time inside my_pow function and return time and res?

Comment: You could do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function **is** running in 0.0001 something seconds. But since the number is so large, it takes almost 3 seconds to print it. So your code is working, I/O(print) is just slow. You can see it yourself if you only print the time it took.

To further demonstrate this and also add emil's comment

```
def decorator_timer(some_function):
    from time import time

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time()
        result = some_function(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time()-t1
        return result, end
    return wrapper


@decorator_timer
def my_pow(a, b):
    res = a ** b
    return res
    # or just return a ** b, it doesn't really matter

result, exec_time = my_pow(99999 , 99999)
print(exec_time) # prints after 0.07347989082336426 seconds
print(result) # takes ~3 seconds
```